# Heatmap over "blocks" of data

Tags: r, heatmap

I am trying to graph a heatmap in R that visualizes the value of datapoints across different data *blocks*. More specifically, I have firm level data for a number of countries. What my heatmap should show is

- Only labels for countries, not firms, while colors are on firm levels
- Black borders that seperate country blocks in the heatmap

The desired output would be similar to this
[image]

Yet, so far I have been failing to meet what I need. Here is a reproducable example, using `ggplot` and `scale_fill_gradient2`, although I am happy to use any other package. Any hint would be much appreciated.

```
 #in matrix form
datanames <- c("ITA_firm1","ITA_firm2","ITA_firm3","GER_firm1","GER_firm2","FRA_firm1","FRA_firm2","FRA_firm3","US_firm1","US_firm2")
data <- matrix(rexp(100, rate=.1), ncol=10)
rownames(data) <- colnames(data) <- datanames

#long and rename to country blocks
library(data.table)
data <- as.data.table(data)
data[,i:= substr(colnames(data),1,3)]
data <- melt(data, id.vars = "i", value.name = "value", variable.name = "j")
data[,j := substr(j,1,3)]

#a graph
ggplot(data , aes(x = j, y = i)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="navy", mid="green",  high="red", 
                       midpoint=mean(data$value), limits=range(data$value)) +
  theme_classic()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to achieve this is by making use of `facet_grid`.

1. Map the firms on `x` and `y`
2. Facet the plot by countries using `facet_grid` and switch the facet labels,
3. Remove the axis title, text and ticks
4. Position the facet labels outside, remove the spacing between facets and the border around the facet labels
5. Add black borders around the panels and set the fill color to `NA`
6. Put the panel on top

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

set.seed(42)
#in matrix form
datanames <- c("ITA_firm1","ITA_firm2","ITA_firm3","GER_firm1","GER_firm2","FRA_firm1","FRA_firm2","FRA_firm3","US_firm1","US_firm2")
data <- matrix(rexp(100, rate=.1), ncol=10)
rownames(data) <- colnames(data) <- datanames

data1 <- as.data.frame(data) %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  pivot_longer(-rowname) %>% 
  separate(rowname, into = c("country1", "firm1")) %>% 
  separate(name, into = c("country2", "firm2"))

#a graph
ggplot(data1, aes(x = firm2, y = firm1, fill = value)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="navy", mid="green",  high="red", 
                       midpoint=mean(data1$value), limits=range(data1$value)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0), limits = rev(levels(data1$firm1))) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  facet_grid(country1 ~ country2, switch = "both") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(), 
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "pt"),
        strip.background = element_rect(color = NA),
        panel.background = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA),
        panel.ontop = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks very good! In my institution I do not have access to the newest version of tidyr (and therefore pivot_longer does not work). I will run this approach tonight from my private computer to see how the mapping works exactly you suggest - and then accept the answer. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi Luks. You are welcome. You can replace the code line with `pivot_longer` using the retired `tidyr::gather` like so: `gather(key = "name", value = "value", -rowname)`.

Comment: I corrected a small error in the code and updated the graph. Of course, the empty rows and columns are a little ugly in an unbalanced sample.  scales = "free" in the facet_grid subcommand would help to some degree but not entirely...